# PHP | .htpasswd | Can not login custom admin page with same username and password

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I use a free shared php web server for my site. my site's url end was p.ht and for some issues it changed to w.pw

In order to make my site working properly again, by using Notepad++ I used "Find in Files" subwindow which is in ctrl+F popup window. I replaced each occurence of p.ht with w.pw.

My site then started to work properly again with no problem in terms of viewing.

however after this change, after a while I needed to logon my custom admin page (approve comments, articles etc)

I created it with .htaccess with main commands below:

```
AuthUserFile /home/u999999999/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthName "Log In"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /adminfolder/
```

just before URLs changed, everything was working on my site properly, I was able to login to my admin account from my firm computer. But know despite the same password and username I can't logon. I changed the password, uploaded new file but again I couldn't logon.

What can be the problem?

1. my firm firewall, security politics update etc?
2. A changed php server property in free shared web server?
3. A ctrl+Replace mistake somehow?

I also entered the password by keyboard and by copy-paste.

Can you please guide me for my situation. Where should I look, what new action can I try in order to detect my failure mode?

best regards

Comment: Have you checked any error logs?

Comment: thanks Shamil, where should I look for logs? refreshed filezilla account & there is no log file nowhere.

Comment: That would be better asked towards your host.

Comment: I asked my situation to my host. They said me to try again next day and my issue solved. But I couldn't learn the root cause unfortunately.